# Double cut using on OSX

Tags: osx, cut

Why I can't use cut twice on OSX , meanwhile it's possible in Linux?

E.g.

```
sobakapavlova@bark:final_paper$ping -s 252 -z 0xb8 -c 1000 google.com |cut -d "=" -f4 
PING google.com (74.125.232.230): 252 data bytes
50.826 ms
34.031 ms
30.043 ms
39.310 ms
```

But

```
sobakapavlova@bark:final_paper$ping -s 252 -z 0xb8 -c 1000 google.com |cut -d "=" -f4 | cut -d " " -f1
```

Doesn't return me anything.

Comment: It's an output buffering issue; `cut` buffers its output if it isn't writing to a terminal, and it takes a while to fill the buffer with so little output. Unless you are piping this command to something like `tail -f`, you might want the `-c` option with `ping` to prevent it from running forever; when `ping` exits, so will `cut`, allowing its output buffer to be flushed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a buffering issue (not specific to macOS).  Wait long enough (until the buffer flushes or the `ping` finishes by itself at 1000 iterations) and you will get your output.

Alternatively, use `awk` like this:

```
$ ping ... |  awk -F '[ =]' '{ print $10 }'
```